# Install python module inside of Django project

Tags: python, django

I would like to install a python module inside a Django project. That way i can modify the module to my needs. So when i upload the code to the server, it has the same code as locally. Unlike when i install the module via requirements.txt

For example: i want to customize the ShopifyApi module. So i download the source code to my project. But where do i have to put the module so that is behaves like a normal module?

Because now when i try to import the module with "import shopify" (which works when the module is installed with Pip) Django gives me the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shopify'
```

I have put the ShopifyApi modul code inside a custom shopify Django app.

Comment: The easist way is to put the [`shopify`](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/tree/master/shopify) directory in your project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`). However, I would think twice about "vendoring" an app like this. If you modify it, then it will be more difficult to update it later on. Perhaps you could you "wrap" the module instead, e.g. by subclassing or writing helper functions?

Comment: Fork the project on github, then pip install your fork in your virtualenv using `pip install -e https://github.com/path/to/your/fork.git`. The code is now in `<virtualenv_path>/src` for you to edit and commit back to your fork.